# Check when an animation has ended in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am starting an animation in SVG and when it ends I want to know so that I can execute another function. I've tried with `endEvent="endAnimate()"` but nothing happend. It's possible to check when an animation has ended and if so, can I call another function?

Comment: If you can, please post a jsfiddle.net demo, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, animation elements have an `onend` event that you can use.

> animation event attribute
>
> > An animation event attribute is an event attribute that specifies script to run for a particular animation-related event. See Animation event attributes. The animation event attributes are ‘onbegin’, ‘onend’, ‘onload’ and ‘onrepeat’.

So, if you really want to attach it to an animation element you can use it like `onend="endAnimate()"`

Comment: I've tried, but the function is executed on the begin of the animation and also at the end of the animation.

Comment: Also I've noticed that even I set the same function to onbegin and onend, the first time is run the event for onend...

Comment: I've let the form with onend; I've used an workaround so that the first time when the function is executed, nothing happens.

Comment: Be aware that these events aren't being fired in webkit/blink, see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116595.

Comment: for me and back-to-back animations, the onend() all fires at the same time :(